# Complete lattices in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: lattice-orders

I know that nonempty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are complete lattices.

My question is: what are the complete lattices that are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is there a way to say something like, "$A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a complete lattice if [condition]"?

Comment: $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$ is a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, but it's not complete...

Comment: Why is it not complete?

Comment: For example, $$\bigvee[-1,0)=0=\bigwedge(0,1],$$ but $0$ doesn't belong to the lattice. Indeed, there is no join of $[-1,0)$ in the lattice, neither there is a meet of $(0,1]$.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I should ask the question, when is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a complete lattice? Is it required to be closed? Or compact?